# Is there a way in cognos platform java sdk to query user specific reports directly from admin login?

Tags: sdk, report, cognos

I tried to query reports from **cognos** via **java sdk** from content manager via admin login using query function (ref: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=methods-querysearchpath-properties-sortby-options) is it posible to **query reports** based on policy or permission such that all **reports accessible to given user** can be retrived directly **via admin login** and not via specific user login..., or any other approach to perform above mentioned.

Comment: accessibility tag is for help solving issues that affect users with disabilities so I removed the tag for you. Hope you get an answer!

Comment: Do you mean something like, Is there a way to produce a list of every report a specific user can run (or navigate to, or edit)?  That would make this a question about permissions.  While Cognos SDK **may be** a tool to use to get to a solution, that could be used through Java or C#, so this is not a Java question.  It is also not about developing reports.  By including the extra tags, you are needlessly attracting the attention of people with expertise unrelated to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: its my first question not familiar with tags, removed it by the way, thanks for your reply.